# How to extract a value from string in php

Tags: php

I have a string value from which i need to extract the value1 , is there a php function which can be tweaked and used, in order to cover edge cases

```
 "value1=php; value2=.php.net; Expires=Nov, 12-May-2020 20:51:23 GMT; Path=/; random;"
```

how to do it?

Comment: A regex would be the quickest way to do it

Comment: Yes regex and check for first =

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `preg_match` and the regex `/value1=(.*?);/` to capture the content.

```
$s = "value1=php; value2=.php.net; Expires=Nov, 12-May-2020 20:51:23 GMT Path=/; random;";

preg_match("/value1=(.*?);/", $s, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]); => php
```